# Sharding With Mongodb Hadoop Connector

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, sharding

HI i have the same case as mentioned in this question [Hadoop HDFS MapReduce output into MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499447/hadoop-hdfs-mapreduce-output-into-mongodb)

I just want to use Hadoop to do Map Reduce (MR) from Mongodb and then the outputs are to be written back into MongoDB as collections. Though the above question has not been solved yet, i have more issue with this scenario. Here i need the output of MR to be written into MongoDB shards and to be sharded correctly.

My question, is it possible to do such scenario since even i did that MR using MongoDB (not Hadoop), i got the output not split correctly into sharded servers and got duplicated output on the result. If it's possible how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is your question? You are going to write your code to write to a MongoDB collection.This is either Java by native or other language interface for the mapReduce job. You are just writing output to a collection. Sharding is part of how you configure the servers, not part of your application. BTW Unaccepted does not mean un-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You write to mongo as usual.  The fact that your mongo db is set to run on shards is a detail that is hidden from you.